# Wait for async loaded classes to finish (without callback)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

What's the proper way to wait for classes loaded asynchronously before calling on them?

*Note: I'm in a complicated situation where I can't use the async load callback.*

Is this the best way to do it?

```
callClassFunction : function () {
  try {
    waitingOnThisClass.someFunction();
  } catch (e) {
    setTimeout("superClass.callClassFunction()",250);
  }
}
```

*jQuery ways are worth mentioning if there are any...

Comment: What are `asynchronous classes`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well. if jQuery is allowed -jquery promise interface and  jQuery.Deferred is just the thing:

```
// Create a Deferred and return its Promise
function asyncEvent(){
    var dfd = new jQuery.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function(){
        dfd.resolve("hurray");
    }, Math.floor(Math.random()*1500));
    setTimeout(function(){
        dfd.reject("sorry");
    }, Math.floor(Math.random()*1500));
    return dfd.promise();
}

// Attach a done and fail handler for the asyncEvent
$.when( asyncEvent() ).then(
    function(status){
        alert( status+', things are going well' );
    },
    function(status){
            alert( status+', you fail this time' );
    }
);
```

Another example;

```
function doAjax(){
   return $.get('foo.htm');
}

function doMoreAjax(){
   return $.get('bar.htm');
}

$.when( doAjax(), doMoreAjax() )
   .then(function(){
      console.log( 'I fire once BOTH ajax requests have completed!' );
   })
   .fail(function(){
      console.log( 'I fire if one or more requests failed.' );
   });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info!  I gotta look into this jQuery solution after the weekend!

Comment: Awesome! Somehow jquery 1.5 breaks my platform, but this is definitely going to come in handy in the future!

Comment: I'm glad it helped:) I'm using deferreds in many projects - they definately come very handy when multiple async calls have to be handled.

Answer (score 2):

One change I would make is to get rid of the try/catch and instead test if the function exists (yet):

```
callClassFunction : function () {
  if (waitingOnThisClass && waitingOnThisClass.someFunction)
    waitingOnThisClass.someFunction();
  else
    setTimeout(superClass.callClassFunction,250);
}
```

Note that you don't need to explicitly say

```
if (waitingOnThisClass != undefined
    && typeof waitingOnThisClass.someFunction === "function")
```

because if they exist as objects/functions they'll evaluate as "truthy".

(If you do use a try/catch and the function has loaded but has some error in it won't that trigger the catch and just rerun the function again repeatedly?)

Comment: Is that true? I tried with facebook's Javascript API `if (FB)` and IE broke saying FB is undefined...as if it broke by just being in the conditional...I'll try adding the function in there and see. Thanks! I'll come back to this forum on Monday

Comment: +1 Thanks as well for pointing out the problem with try/catch